# Change ImageView src for multilanguage on Android

Tags: android, imageview, multilingual

I have to use multilanguage, and I am using a string.xml for each language for texts of buttons, textviews and edittexts, and it works. But i need to change some imageviews android:src for each language too, how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save those drawables in folders named following this name convection: drawable-language-screen. Ie: drawable-es-xhdpi/image.png

Comment: It is showing the message: "Failed to convert @drawable/image into a drawable
Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/image
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log" when i try to use android:src="@drawable/image"

Comment: Erm that's weird. Take a look at this, I just tried it and it's working on my IDE (Android Studio)

http://git.oneoctopus.es/public/index.php/langdrawables.git/tree/master/LangDrawables/src/main/